# Why is the supplied parameter considered by SSRS to be unsupplied?

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, parameters, parameter-passing, bids

I am trying to run a report I created and got it to the point where the parameters I created for the report display when the report is run as they should, but when I select "View Report" I eventually get this err msg:

[image]

As you can see, though, the control (dropdown list) for the Unit parameter is being generated (and it is being populated) and I selected a value (the exact value is obfuscated in the screamshot above). Yet, after some churning, that err msg appears.

How can that be? After all, the Unit parameter WAS supplied, ISTM.

It's not a problem with the server configuration or so, because I get the same exact fingerwag when trying to run it locally from the report's Preview tab:

[image]

HOWEVER, if I execute the Stored Procedure from the report's Data tab, by selecting the Dataset that I've set up for the Stored Procedure and supplying the same three values as above (just as I do from SSRS and from the Preview tab), all goes well - there is no err msg and lots of data is returned.

Why is the entered value for "Unit" passed through fine in the latter case, but not the other two?

### UPDATE

Here are all the references to "Unit" in the report's .rdl (XML) file:

```
<ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="BegDate">
      <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>Begin Date</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="EndDate">
      <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>End Date</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="Unit">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>Unit</Prompt>
      <ValidValues>
        <DataSetReference>
          <DataSetName>UnitsQuery</DataSetName>
          <ValueField>Unit</ValueField>
          <LabelField>Unit</LabelField>
        </DataSetReference>
      </ValidValues>
    </ReportParameter>
</ReportParameters>
```

So "Unit" is among the ReportParameters, and that's why I see it along with the two Date params.

But why is it the only field in the Stored Procedure's dataset:

```
<DataSet Name="PriceVarianceSP">
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="Unit">
      <DataField>Unit</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>PlatypusData</DataSourceName>
    <CommandType>StoredProcedure</CommandType>
    <CommandText>priceAndUsageVariance</CommandText>
  </Query>
</DataSet>
```

Shouldn't it have either all three fields, or none of them? Why would one of them be given "special" consideration?

```
<DataSet Name="UnitsQuery">
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="Unit">
      <DataField>Unit</DataField>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>PlatypusData</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>select distinct Unit from duckbills order by unit</CommandText>
    <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
  </Query>
</DataSet>
```

But the problem seems to be that it's *missing* from somewhere, not that it's somewhere it doesn't belong, or...???

Should "Unit" be removed from one dataset ("PriceVarianceSP") or another ("UnitsQuery")?

The only references to the two date params, BegDate and EndDate, are in the ReportParameters section.

As some may want/need to see it to grok this, and since the *.rdl file is not too large or complex (yet?), here it is in its entirety:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition"xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="PlatypusData">
      <rd:DataSourceID>875e488f-a3fc-4066-befb-5b85a938f58d</rd:DataSourceID>
      <DataSourceReference>PlatypusData</DataSourceReference>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <InteractiveHeight>11in</InteractiveHeight>
  <ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="BegDate">
      <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>Begin Date</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="EndDate">
      <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>End Date</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="Unit">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Prompt>Unit</Prompt>
      <ValidValues>
        <DataSetReference>
          <DataSetName>UnitsQuery</DataSetName>
          <ValueField>Unit</ValueField>
          <LabelField>Unit</LabelField>
        </DataSetReference>
      </ValidValues>
    </ReportParameter>
  </ReportParameters>
  <rd:DrawGrid>true</rd:DrawGrid>
  <InteractiveWidth>8.5in</InteractiveWidth>
  <rd:SnapToGrid>true</rd:SnapToGrid>
  <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
  <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
  <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
  <rd:ReportID>badCompany7a923-1452-4e00-9cc3-1f437ad70ef6</rd:ReportID>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="PriceVarianceSP">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="Unit">
          <DataField>Unit</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>PlatypusData</DataSourceName>
        <CommandType>StoredProcedure</CommandType>
        <CommandText>priceAndUsageVariance</CommandText>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="UnitsQuery">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="Unit">
          <DataField>Unit</DataField>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>PlatypusData</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>select distinct Unit from duckbills order by unit</CommandText>
        <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <Width>33in</Width>
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Textbox Name="textbox1">
        <rd:DefaultName>textbox1</rd:DefaultName>
        <Style>
          <Color>SteelBlue</Color>
          <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
          <FontSize>20pt</FontSize>
          <FontWeight>700</FontWeight>
          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
        <Height>0.36in</Height>
        <Value>PriceAndUsageVarianceReport</Value>
      </Textbox>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>2.29in</Height>
  </Body>
  <Language>en-US</Language>
  <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
</Report>
```

Does anything jump/stand/stick out about this that could be causing this problem?

### UPDATE 2

If I remove the first dataset Fields section ("PriceVarianceSP"), there's no difference.

If I remove both of the dataset Fields sections (also the one in "UnitsQuery"), I get:

*The report parameter ‘Unit’ uses the field ‘Unit’ in a dataset reference, but the dataset ‘UnitsQuery’ does not contain that field. (rsInvalidDataSetReferenceField)*

### UPDATE 3

To be clear about what is/not happening in the designer, I can go the report's data tab and select the Run ("!") button and see this:

[image]

When I supply the parameters, I get data:

[image]

However, if I go to the Preview tab of the designer, which supplies the correct controls to provide the parameters, and I enter the same params and then mash the "View Report" button, I get the err msg as shown above in the first image.

Why would the Preview tab (and the report in SSRS) not see that the Unit parameter has been provided, whereas the Data tab does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908470/what-is-the-difference-between-how-the-data-and-preview-data-generation-work).

Basically, you need to configure the Dataset Parameters within the BIDS project.